# What's the most scalable way to track user activity?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, language-agnostic

I would like to track certain user activity and limit this activity using a time constraint. An example of this could be the votes per day limit enforced by SO. Which of the following methods provides a better solution in terms of scalability and ease of use?

- Store activity info in the database
- Store activity info in the application scope
- Use an entirely different method to track this information

**Method 1:**

- **Advantages**: data integrity, which is not important in my use case.
- **Disadvantages**: requires database interaction, stores redundant data, requires a scheduled event to reset the values being tracked

**Method 2**

- **Advantages**: does not require database interaction, appears to be easier
- **Disadvantages**: I'm unsure of the implications on application memory given a large user-base to track, or how easy it is to find and manipulate struct data with hundreds of keys

I'm using ColdFusion with MySQL, if this matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only care about this data on a per-person basis, and won't be getting aggregates of this, I'd suggest you go with a key/val store that supports TTL.  [Redis](http://redis.io/) sounds like it fits your requirements pretty well.

- Though it runs in memory, it does snapshot to disk periodically (which mean it's fast, and if something goes down, you'll get most everything back).
- Easy interaction, as with your "method 2", but without having to worry about managing a large in-memory structure.

**Example Setup**

Going with the SO points-per-day scenario, we'll have a time-frame of one day, and our value will be a simple value that increments on some user activity.

Our key would be a combination of the user's id and the current timeframe (day, in this case).  After we have set the key, we set a ttl, which means after today is up, the key will eventually expire and clean itself up.

```
redis> incr user123-2011-10-09
(integer) 1  # no value found for key, defaulting to 1
             # if this key already had a value it would be incremented.

redis> expire user123-2011-10-09 86400
(integer) 1  # expiration of 1 day was successful

redis> get user123-2011-10-09
"1"          # current value of user key
```

More info on these commands (incr, get, expire, and ttl would be of most interest to you) can be found on the [redis commands reference](http://redis.io/commands) (complete with an interactive shell to try these things out).

**Edit**

This method could obviously be applied with any number of k/v stores, I've used Redis here as a concrete example since I believe it meets the requirements closely.